# 2sxc: data-list App related questions

Tags: 2sxc

I have a list named 'Announcements' (created in the 2sxc app administration), It is used for 'Announcements-built-in-board' App on DNN portal and is an 2sxc App.

My questions are:

1. Why I cannot delete / unpublished a record from the floating toolbar?
   I can be delete it from the ***App Data Administration***, but not any other way.
           a. The toolbar is created for each item in the list (in the following snippet, it is item 700)
           b. The **(U)** in the `id` of `ul`' stands for announcements ***USER*** [can be either (U) or **(SU)** for
               ***ADMINISTRATOR***]
           c. A record could be deleted / unpublished either by a user who is a member of a role
                named 'Announcements' or by Administrator
   [Screenshot of the toolbar here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGH8I.png)

`<div name="divInfoInAnnouncement">
    <ul id='ulItem_700_Menu_(U)' name='ulItem_700_Menu_(U)' class='sc-menu' data-toolbar='[ { "attributeSetName" : "Announcements", "action" : "new", "sortOrder" : 0, "prefill" : { "UID" : 2, "PublishDate" : "2016-09-15 09:56", "PublishedBy" : "Usr1)" } }, { "attributeSetName" : "Announcements", "entityId" : "700", "action" : "edit", "sortOrder" : 0 }, { "attributeSetName" : "Announcements", "entityId" : "700", "action" : "remove", "sortOrder" : 0 }, { "entityId" : "700", "attributeSetName" : "Announcements", "action" : "publish", "sortOrder" : 0 }, { "attributeSetName" : "Announcements", "action" : "more", "sortOrder" : 0 } ]'></ul>
</div>`

2. Can I send mail -- in some automated way -- with the announcement content **after** the user saved the message -- as respond to **SAVE**?

I'm using the default dialog for add/new (not customized in any way).
[Screenshot of the editor dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSRNV.png)

This is the list structure:
`Static Name      | Data Type | Input Type  | Label
------------------|-----------|-------------|-------------------
UID               | Number    | default     | User ID
AnnouncementTitle | String    | default     | Announcement Title
PublishDate       | DateTime  | default     | Publish Date
PublishedBy       | String    | default     | Publisher Name
AnnouncementBody  | String    | wysiwyg-dnn | Announcement Body
ExpirationDate    | DateTime  | default     | Expiration Date
Attachments       | Hyperlink | library     | Attachments`

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not unpublish from toolbar: since unpublishing is meant to usually prevent draft changes from going out, and only secondarily as a "hide existing" method, it's currently not important enough to add load to the toolbar. so at the moment, that's why it's not in the toolbar once it's published. this also helps to visualize unpublished, as there is often no other visible queue.
2. why not delete from toolbar: many users have difficulties telling the difference between remove and delete, so to protect them, at the moment only remove is available. delete as a real delete is fairly new and was added to the admin-ui only a few months back. I believe it will be added at some time - but we first have to ensure that users won't confuse delete with remove. So at the moment not a priority.
3. if you want to create your own delete buttons, you can do that; just call the correct web apis
4. I'm a bit confused about the rest, but I believe you would like to provide some buttons to some users in a group, but not to others. for this it's probably best to create a custom toolbar with @Edit.Toolbar(...) and show a different one (from the server) based on the permissions - pretty straight forward
5. sending a mail or any other custom action on a default save-event is currently not possible. it's been requested a few times but is not a top priority, as it would require a lot of architecting to get it perfect.

hope this helped :)

Comment: Hello.
As for 1 and 2: Un-publish / delete -- not doing anything... This is the main reason for the question - it look like the postback is firing, but no Un-Publish / Delete.  

As for 3: where can I get API documentation?  

As for 4: I only want to floating buttons to be right of the title.  

as for 5: any way of kind of "hacking" this? The is -- per my boss request -- essential...  
Sorry for "nagging"...

Comment: about #3 the api isn't fully documented, also because there's still a low risk that we may change something. once we document it, we have to stay very, very stable. So for now you'll just have to check the code and live with a small risk, that it may still change 1-2 times till we then do documnent/finalize it.

Comment: Sorry:  
5 was missing a bit of text: it is in relation to sending mail after adding new record.  
1. Any thing I can do about it?
2. Can you tell me what is the name of the table where the list is stored so (maybe) I'll create a trigger (or something alike)?

Comment: @DMagician since it's an EAV model, the most important for you would be the ToSic....Entities table, which should at least get an update (modified) date change.